# Unhandled Exception (C)

Tags: c, compiler-errors, unhandled-exception

I'm try to make a program that import a grid from a data file and does something with it, but I'm running into problems when trying to import the grid into a multidimensional array.

I'm getting an "Unhandled Exception" error with the if-else statement inside my while loop. When I comment out this part of my code it runs perfectly.

```
int main( void ) {
    FILE* grid = fopen( FILE_NAME, "r" );
    int row = 0;
    int column = 0;
    int intGrid[21][21];

    // Null check omitted for space.

    while( fscanf( grid, "%d ", &intGrid[row][column] ) == 1 ) { // Loads the grid into an array
        if( intGrid[row][column] != -1 )
            column++;
        else
            column = 0;
            row++;
    }
```

Can anyone please spot the problem in my code.

Comment: There are no exceptions in C, so any message like this must be coming from the C runtime libraries.

Comment: Your indentation is wrong. Use curly braces...

Comment: Wow, you're right, that was extraordinarily dumb of me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Missing brackets:

```
else { 
    column = 0;
    row++;
}
```

Withot brackets the `row` is always incremented and would quickly run out of array dimensions.